# How to get get exact words started by special letters by use method startsWith in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I want  get exact words started by special letters by use method startsWith() from list []  for show this words in List View builder .
this images for erorr and content list
[content list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W0zXC.png)
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B5JYw.png)

```
class searchBooks extends SearchDelegate<String> {
  var list;
  searchBooks({this.list});
  @override
  List<Widget> buildActions(BuildContext context) {
    return [
      IconButton(
        onPressed: () {
          query = "";
        },
        icon: Icon(Icons.clear),
      )
    ];
  }

  //icon leading
  @override
  Widget buildLeading(BuildContext context) {
    return IconButton(
      icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
      onPressed: () {
        close(context, "d");
      },
    );
  }

  // result
  @override
  Widget buildResults(BuildContext context) {
    return Text('body  ressult');
  }

//show when someone search book
  @override
  Widget buildSuggestions(BuildContext context) {
    List searchBook;
    searchBook =
        query.isEmpty ? list : list.where((p) => p.startsWith(query)).toList();
    return ListView.builder(
      itemBuilder: (context, i) {
        return ListTile(
          leading: Icon(
            Icons.book,
            color: Colors.green,
          ),
          title: Text("${searchBook[i]}"),
        );
      },
      itemCount: searchBook.length,
    );
  }
}
```

i called this class here

```
          title: Text('الأقسام'),
          centerTitle: true,
          backgroundColor: Colors.greenAccent,
          elevation: 5,
          actions: <Widget>[
            IconButton(
                icon: Icon(Icons.search),
                onPressed: () {
                  showSearch(
                      context: context,
                      delegate: searchBooks(list: lisrSearch));
                })
          ],
        ),
```

this error

```
════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following _TypeError was thrown building _SearchPage<String>(dirty, dependencies: [_LocalizationsScope-[GlobalKey#87f80], _InheritedTheme], state: _SearchPageState<String>#cdfe7):
type '(dynamic) => dynamic' is not a subtype of type '(dynamic) => bool' of 'test'

The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  MaterialApp file:///E:/test/flutter_appggg/lib/main.dart:11:12
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      searchBooks.buildSuggestions (package:flutterappggg/pages/catigories.dart:143:46)
#1      _SearchPageState.build (package:flutter/src/material/search.dart:532:34)
#2      StatefulElement.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4691:27)
#3      ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4574:15)
#4      StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4746:11)
```

Answer (score 0):

Half of Dart problems could be solved if one declare explicitely their variable types.

Here's a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your problem:

```py
class Foo {
  var list;
  
  Foo({this.list});
  
  void search(String query) {
    List searchBook = query.isEmpty ? list : list.where((p) => p.startsWith(query)).toList();
    print(searchBook);
  }
}


void main() {
  var words = ["abc", "def", "ghi", "jkl", "axy"];
  Foo(list: words).search("a");
}
```

This raises

```
TypeError: type '(dynamic) => dynamic' is not a subtype of type '(String) => bool'
```

Note that I'm not declaring the types of `list`, `searchBook` and `words`. Declare them and the error goes away:

```
class Foo {
  List<String> list;
  
  Foo({this.list});
  
  void search(String query) {
    List<String> searchBook = query.isEmpty ? list : list.where((p) => p.startsWith(query)).toList();
    print(searchBook);
  }
}


void main() {
  List<String> words = ["abc", "def", "ghi", "jkl", "axy"];
  Foo(list: words).search("a");
}
```

This now outputs

```
[abc, axy]
```